# Fixing incorrect 'NAA' flags in the queue

Tags: feature-request, review, flags, moderation, 10k-tools

In the last few days I noticed the several hundred flags and thought I'd chip in. I've been noticing that a lot of flags in the Not An Answer queue are really attempts to answer the question. Just really poor ones.

When I myself started flagging, I flagged some answers incorrectly too using "Not An Answer" for things that were just *really* poor attempts to answer the question.

---

#### So, I'd like to make a feature request:

Whenever:

- A user sees the 10K moderation tools for the first time they get a "welcome screen" explaining what to use flags (like not an answer) for and what not to. This way flags will be invalidated a lot faster.
- A user flags for the first time with a given reason - they get a screen explaining that flag reason and they click 'yes' again
- Every time a guest flags they get the same screen users get when they flag for the first time.

Additionally, in the flag dialog ("I am flagging this answer because") there should be little `(?)`s next to the close reasons explaining each one in depth (linking to meta posts).

Both these seem rather easy to implement and I believe would save the community a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Note: While this is relevant to all flags, I'm keeping the title as NAA specific since this is the "Big" issue I see here. If you strongly disagree please feel free to edit the title and/or this post as you please as long as the intent remains clear

Comment: I quite often disagree with already existing NAA flags and most of them end up being disputed...